# Determining the dimensions of the eigenspaces of a matrix given its characteristic equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have a $6$x$6$ matrix with the characteristic equation

$$\lambda^2 (\lambda - 1)(\lambda - 2)^3 = 0$$

How can I use this to find *all* possible dimensions for eigenspaces of the matrix, *without* assigning values?

Comment: The characteristic equation should have degree 6, since the matrix is 6x6.

Comment: @user84413 good catch. Edit made

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The geometric multiplicity $\gamma(\lambda) = \dim \operatorname{eigenspace}(\lambda)$ associated to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ can be anything between $1$ and the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$. Here the possibilities are: $\gamma(0) = 1$ or $\gamma(0) = 2$; $\gamma(1) = 1$; $\gamma(2) = 1$ or $\gamma(2) = 2$ or $\gamma(2) = 3$. To actually realize these as matrices, you may use Jordan normal forms and that fact that $\gamma(\lambda)$ equals the number of Jordan blocks corresponding to $\lambda$. For example, the case $\gamma(0) = 1$, $\gamma(1) = 1$ and $\gamma(2)=2$ can be realized as $$\begin{pmatrix}0 &1 & & & & \\ &0 & & & & \\ & &1 & & & \\ & & &2 & 1& \\ & & & &2 & \\ & & & & & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$
(Blank entries are zero.)

Another example: the following three matrices have characteristic polynomial $\lambda^3$ and have respective geometric multiplicities $\gamma(0) = 1$, $\gamma(0) = 2$, $\gamma(0) = 3$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0& 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: What function is $\gamma$ supposed to represent? I'm still unsure of how I am able to find the dimension of the kernel (or eigenspace) when just given the characteristic equation?

Comment: @cbutler16 I edited it in for clarity. The geometric multiplicity, by definition, *is* the dimension of the $\lambda$-eigenspace.

Comment: I'm still unsure of how I am able to find the dimension of the kernel (or eigenspace) when just given the characteristic equation? That is, how are you getting the values for $\gamma$?

Comment: @cbutler16 The dimension is not uniquely determined by the characteristic polynomial. It can take every value between $1$ and the algebraic multiplicity (exponent appearing in the characteristic polynomial). I'll add another example.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the dimension of each eigenspace is at most the algebraic multiplicity of the corresponding eigenvalue, so

1) The eigenspace for $\lambda=1$ has dimension 1

2) The eigenspace for $\lambda=0$ has dimension 1 or 2

3) The eigenspace for $\lambda=2$ has dimension 1, 2, or 3.